# 3D Sound not working with spacial blend set to 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, 3d

I want the sound of a telephone ringing to get louder the closer you are to the object and quieter the further away you are until you can no longer hear the noise.

I have set up an audiosource on the object, added the clip and set the spacial blend to 3d and played around with the sound setttings, but nothing I do seems to get it to work. The volume is always consistently loud or quiet depending on settings and moving towards/away the source doesn't change the volume at all.

I have tried tweaking every setting, tried logarithmic and linear rolloff and I just can't get it to work. Here is a screenshot of the current settings, but I have tweaked most of them.

Can anyone offer advice on what I might be missing?

Settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utzdx.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed this. It was because I had 2 audio listeners in the scene. One on the camera attached to my player and one on a camera that was being used for a tv screen. I removed the second audio listener and it worked as intended. Knew I was missing something obvious.